# Create new rows depending on values in Hive/Impala

Tags: sql, hive, impala

I am trying to do an operation on Hive/Impala and I don't know how to continue. First, I explain what I want to do. I have the following table:

[image]

Well, I want to create a new row for each missing position, and assign it a zero value. The table would look like this:

[image]

I do not know if it is possible to create this functionality in Hive or Impala, either one would suit me.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @GordonLinoff's answer, i get what I want, but i made some changes. Basically, it is what he says, but splitting his answer in two different queries. This is because in Hive you can not do LATERAL VIEW and JOIN in the same query. The solution would be:

```
create table t1 as 
select i, x 
from (select max(position) as max_position from t) p 
lateral view posexplode(split(space(p.max_position), ' ')) pe as i, x

select a.i, coalesce(b.value, 0) as value
from t1 a LEFT JOIN t b
on a.i = b.position
where a.i != 0
```

Thanks Gordon!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a trick in Hive where you generate a string of spaces and then split the string into an array and turn the array into a table:

```
select pe.i, coalesce(t.value, 0) as value
from (select i, x
      from (select max(position) as max_position
            from t
           ) p lateral view 
           posexplode(split(space(p.max_position), ' ')) pe as i, x
     ) pe left join
     t
     on pe.i = t.position;
```

Comment: I am trying what you wrote, but an error occurs: 'Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10085]: line 10:13 JOIN with a LATERAL VIEW is not supported'

Comment: Pls note you need to use `hive` and not impala.

Comment: Yeah, I am doing it in Hive, and it is not working. It seems that we can not do a LATERAL VIEW operation with JOIN.

Comment: @SergioVivasPleite . . . It should work with a subquery.

Comment: It worked! Take a look to my answer! Thanks Gordon.

Comment: Isn't that the same as the edited answer I posted yesterday?